# Adding Text Tool,drag,drop and resize it on Html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building an HTML5 canvas application. In that i need to add a Text to the canvas,drag,drop and resize it on the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these two examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text

I have build an example that can help you on what you need to do:
http://jsbin.com/ufiSilu/1/

JavaScript code:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById(data).innerHTML,10,50);

}
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
    ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">    
</canvas>

<p id="myText" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> drag me </p>
```

CSS:

```
#myCanvas {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
```

hope it helps.